# Angular2 interpolation bracket notation (instead of dot) for variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, interpolation, angular-template

I'm wondering if there's a Angular2 equivalent to the bracket notation in Javascript that lets you use variables to select an object property. Or a way of doing the same thing.

**Consider this code:**

```
 let selector = "foo";
 let someObject = {foo: "some content", guu: "some other content"};
 console.log(someObject[selector]); //bracket notation, logs "some content"
```

**I've tried the following in Angular2:**

```
  {{someObject[selector]}}
  {{someObject['selector']}}
```

Neither worked. Is there another way of doing it without Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work just fine in Angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mrky5n.

Some reasons that it may not be working in your current application:

1) If `selector` is a variable with a string selector in it, perhaps that `selector` variable is not available to the scope of the template (e.g. it's `private` on the component class, defined within a method, or lifecycle hook, etc.

2) If `selector` is the property you actually want to access, perhaps there is a typo in the name of `selector` -- maybe the real property is `selectro` or `selecter`. This is a reason to not use this approach, since you lose Typescript's type checking. `someObject.selectorr` throws an error while `someObject['selectorr']` goes through fine.

3) That property has not received a value yet -- maybe the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) would help.

Comment: Crap, should have checked I'm trying `someObject?[selector]` ... is there a way to do that?

Comment: Glad I could help :) -- doesn't seem to be working. You may be able to use a ternary to get around it `someObject ? someObject[selector] : null`

Comment: Consider upvoting and / or accepting if this answer was helpful so others know that your question is answered. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular [template syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions) supports many JS features, including bracket notation.

`{{someObject[selector]}}` expression assumes that both `someObject` and `selector` are component properties. This won't work if they are local variables that are defined with `let`.